# How to specify as the type angular.service?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have TypeScript code:

```
// app.js
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { Deamon } from 'Deamon';

angular.module('app')
    .service('deamon', DeamonClass);

// Deamon.ts
export class DeamonClass {
    $inject = [
        '$vk'
    ];
    constructor(private $vk: any) {} // <- $vk is my another service VkClass
}
```

How do I specify the type from $vk? If I point as the type name of the class,

```
 constructor(private $vk: VkClass) {}
```

then nothing does not compile.

Comment: you need to add `import` statement for VkClass, make sure that you also export that class

Comment: @entre, and it will not cause duplication of code? I am a beginner and do not fully understand how the import works. Importing will create a variable - an instance of the class?

Comment: Yes and no, If you try to construct an instance of that class then of course the compiler will need to pull it in for you. However, if you are just using that import for type information I don't believe that import will trickle down to the compiled JS.

Comment: if you work with c# is similar to `using`, it is just for referencing the types. instances are always created only when you do `new xyz()`